# PHP echo overwriting page on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a page that aims to document borrowed resources. I'd like to ensure fields aren't empty before inserting a new record into the database. When empty fields are found, I inform the user through an alert box.

The problem I'm having is once the alert is displayed, everything that takes place after the "if empty" block is removed from the page. How can I create the alert box without having this happen?

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Resource Tracker</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pure-min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css">

  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Resource Tracker</h1>

    <?php 
    // Form to insert new items
    echo
    "<form method='POST' action='index.php' class='pure-form'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Add new item</legend>

      <input type='text' name='contact' placeholder='Contact'>
      <input type='text' name='resource' placeholder='Resource Borrowed'>
      <input type='text' name='returnDate' class='input-append date myDatepicker' id='example1' placeholder='Return Date'>

      <button type='submit' name='insertButton' class='pure-button pure-button-primary'>Add</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>";

    if (isset($_POST['insertButton'])) {
      $contact = trim($_POST["contact"]);
      $resource = trim($_POST["resource"]);
      $returnDate = trim($_POST["returnDate"]);

      if(empty($contact)) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Contact infomation is not valid.');</script>";
        return;
      }
      if (empty($resource)) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Resource infomation is not valid.');</script>";
        return;
      }
      if (empty($returnDate)) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Return date infomation is not valid.');</script>";
        return;
      }

      $current_date = date('F d, Y');
      $sql = "insert into borrowed_assets values ('$contact', '$resource', '" . $current_date . "', '$returnDate')";

      $servername = "********.com";
      $username = "********";
      $password = "********";
      $dbname = "resource_tracker";
      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 
      // Insert into database
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      mysqli_close($conn);

      // Reload page to prevent duplicate submitions
      header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
      exit();
    }
  ?>

  <table class="pure-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="23.75%">Contact</th>
        <th width="23.75%">Resource Borrowed</th>
        <th width="23.75%">Date Requested</th>
        <th width="23.75%">Return Date</th>
        <th width="5%">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <?php
        $servername = "********.com";
        $username = "********";
        $password = "********";
        $dbname = "resource_tracker";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM borrowed_assets";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        mysqli_close($conn);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td id='contact'>" . $row["contact"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td id='asset'>" . $row["asset"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td id='request_date'>" . $row["request_date"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td id='return_date'>" . $row["return_date"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><img src='glyphicons-17-bin.png' id='remove' align='center' style='display: block; height: 1.2em; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
          }
        }
      ?>  
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {      
        $('#example1').datepicker({
            format: "MM dd, yyyy"
        });  
     });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('img[src$="glyphicons-17-bin.png"]').click(function(e){
      var fields = [];
      $(this).closest('tr').children().each(function () {
        fields.push(this.innerHTML);
      });
      $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
      fields.pop();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: { record: fields }
      });
    })
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The html generated before a blank insertion looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Resource Tracker</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pure-min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css">

  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Resource Tracker</h1>

    <form method='POST' action='index.php' class='pure-form'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Add new item</legend>

      <input type='text' name='contact' placeholder='Contact'>
      <input type='text' name='resource' placeholder='Resource Borrowed'>
      <input type='text' name='returnDate' class='input-append date myDatepicker' id='example1' placeholder='Return Date'>

      <button type='submit' name='insertButton' class='pure-button pure-button-primary'>Add</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
  <table class="pure-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="23.75%">Contact</th>
        <th width="23.75%">Resource Borrowed</th>
        <th width="23.75%">Date Requested</th>
        <th width="23.75%">Return Date</th>
        <th width="5%">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr><td id='contact'>Bobby Tables</td><td id='asset'>server1234</td><td id='request_date'>August 05, 2015</td><td id='return_date'>September 04, 2015</td><td><img src='glyphicons-17-bin.png' id='remove' align='center' style='display: block; height: 1.2em; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'></td></tr>  
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {      
        $('#example1').datepicker({
            format: "MM dd, yyyy"
        });  
     });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('img[src$="glyphicons-17-bin.png"]').click(function(e){
      var fields = [];
      $(this).closest('tr').children().each(function () {
        fields.push(this.innerHTML);
      });
      $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
      fields.pop();
      // $.post('delete.php', 'record=' + )
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: { record: fields }
      });
      console.log(fields);
    })
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Afterwards it looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Resource Tracker</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pure-min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css">

  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Resource Tracker</h1>

    <form method='POST' action='index.php' class='pure-form'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Add new item</legend>

      <input type='text' name='contact' placeholder='Contact'>
      <input type='text' name='resource' placeholder='Resource Borrowed'>
      <input type='text' name='returnDate' class='input-append date myDatepicker' id='example1' placeholder='Return Date'>

      <button type='submit' name='insertButton' class='pure-button pure-button-primary'>Add</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form><script type='text/javascript'>alert('Contact infomation is not valid.');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `return` at the top level context of your script, so it's effective acting as an `exit()` call.

Comment: Understood, but what should be done instead? I'm tempted to use GOTO here.

Comment: well, frankly, it's a stupid design. let's say you have a 10 required fields form, and the user forgets 4 of them. your design forces 4 full blown roundtrips. "you forgot A" (reload) "you forgot B" (reload), blah blah blah. a proper design would be "you forgot A,B,C,D". queue up the messages, and output all of the errors at once, instead of forcing the user to fix things one-at-a-tediously-painful-time.

Comment: I agree and will change that, but this still doesn't help with the root issue here.

Comment: well, don't "return". if you want the later parts of the page to be output as well, you can't return/exit in any of the error checking stages.

Comment: The next block of code is the part that does the insertion. I think what I should do is set flags in each of the if(empty(...)) blocks. Then do the insertion inside of an if(validContac && validResource...) or similar. We'll see how it goes. Thanks for the input.

Comment: that's pretty much it. `$errors = false; if(something wrong) { $errors = true; $messages[] = 'something dun blowed up'; }`, then output all the messages at once at the end.